# Flutter: facebook_app_events iOS 14 compliance (setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled)

Tags: flutter, dart, facebook-sdk-4.0, ios14, flutter-plugin

Reading through the [Facebook App Events Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios) and general iOS 14 guidelines, it looks like we need to check for ask users for consent for Advertiser tracking any time information is sent to Facebook.

I don't see an API endpoint for the [facebook_app_events](https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_app_events) plugin to use the suggested "setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled" field. Since I'm only using the analytics/app events, is this endpoint required for iOS 14 compliance?

If so, then should I address this with the plugin creator?

Answer (score 2):

Using the same plugin you can add this code to set the tracking

```dart
facebookAppEvents.setAdvertiserTracking(enabled: true);//or false based on users selection
```

Yes as per the comment written on source it seems that its required for ios14 compliance..

> /// Sets the Advert Tracking propeety for iOS advert tracking
> /// an iOS 14+ feature, android should just return a success.